# How is Trika connected with Kaula sampradaya?

Tags: kashmiri-shaivism, trika

Except the fact that Acharya Abhinavgupta was initiated into kaula, is there anything similar in Kaula and Trika? I have heard many saying that Trika or Kashmir shaivism is part of Kaula. And also heard that kula of kashmir shaivism isnt same as Kaula. So, whats true?